# How can i show my panels in the other panes?

Tags: java, javafx

Hi this is my problem i cant show the panels into the root panel, im doing a similar chat some like skype but the part that i need to show(messages), its not showed, when i send the message to the users.
[image]
Well this is my code to send my message:

```
btnSend.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {


            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {


                String empty = "";
                String sendMessage = txtMensajes.getText();
                String[] talkTo_array = lstDisplayBuddys.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().split("-");
                String talkTo = talkTo_array[talkTo_array.length - 1]+"@mpns.mcm.net.mx";

                try{
                    // CONDITION IF ARE EMPTY THE MESSAGES 

                    if (sendMessage.equals(empty)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Add some message");
                    }
                    else{
                        if (talkTo != sendMessage) {
                            while (true) {

                                try {

                                    sendMessage(XMPPChatHelper.encodeBase64(sendMessage), talkTo);
                                    System.out.println("send message");

                                    //SHOW MY MESSAGES WHEN I SEND IT
                                    Platform.runLater(()->{
                                        pnContArea.getChildren().addAll(drawSendMessage(sendMessage));
                                        txtMensajes.setText("");
                                    });



                                } catch (XMPPException e) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            ConnectionDBHistorialHelper ConnectionDBHistorialHelper=new ConnectionDBHistorialHelper();
                            ConnectionDBHistorialHelper.saveMessageSend(sendMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){

                }
            }

        });
```

and this is the method that draw the image and the text into the other panel:

```
public StackPane drawSendMessage(String message){
        StackPane paneSend=new StackPane();
        Platform.runLater(()->{
            Text sendMessageText=new Text(message);
            ImageView imaSend=new ImageView(HomeController.class.getResource("/image/isend.png").toExternalForm());
            paneSend.getChildren().addAll(imaSend,sendMessageText);
            paneSend.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

        });
        return paneSend;
    }
```

thnks advanced.

Answer (score 0):

He he it's very easy to do that you only need to initilize the whatever variable in this case all panes with

```
@FXML private variablePane variable;
```